# Refresh Component on navigator.pop()

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native's Navigator. Is there anyway to refresh the component so when I pop back to it, it'll make a new API call and grab the updated data to display in the component. I found a few similar questions, but no good answer...

Answer (score 4):

Adding Api Call in callBack using a subscription. sovles the issue

```
  componentDidMount() {
     this.props.fetchData();        
     this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'willFocus',
      () => {
        this.props.fetchData();
      }
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can send a callback function to nextscene from previous one as a prop.

```
this.props.navigator.push({
          name: *nextscene*,
          passProps: {
            text: response,
            callBack: this.callback
        });

async callback(){
   await ....//make new api request grab the udpated data
}
```

Then in your nextscene you call callback method and then pop. You can also send parameters

```
 this.props.callBack()
 this.props.navigator.pop()
```

Answer (score 3):

When pop () to refresh before a page is not a good idea

You can try `DeviceEventEmitter` object

- previous page `DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('xxx', callback)` in `componentDidMount`
- current page `DeviceEventEmitter.emit('xxx', anythingInCallback...)` before `pop()`

ps:previous page`DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners('xxx')` in `componentWillUnmount`

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you're still looking for an answer to this, but holy crap has this kept me up tonight. I'm very new to React Native, but I finally had some success.

The [React Navigation API docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) have a section for adding event listeners! Check it out! I shared some of my own code below too.

This is an example event handler in a Component that is the **top** screen of the StackNavigator stack. It grabs the current state and saves to the backend using an API call. After completion, StackNavigator's pop is called.

```
handleSubmit = () => {
  const { value, otherValue } = this.state
  addThingToDatabase({ value, otherValue })
    .then(() => this.props.navigation.pop())
}
```

Now over to the other Component which is the screen "underneath" in the StackNavigator stack. This is screen being shown after the "pop". Here's what I **used to have** in ComponentDidMount.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { index } = this.props.navigation.state.params

  getAllThingsFromDatabase({ index })
    .then(({ arrayOfThings }) => this.setState({
      index,
      arrayOfThings
  }))
}
```

But the Component wouldn't update with the new thing, until addListener! Now I have pretty much the same code except it's in the constructor. I figured I only need to run it one time, and I need to store it too.

```
constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context)

  this.state = {
    index: null,
    arrayOfThings: []
  }

  this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus',
    (payload) => {
      const { index } = payload.state.params
      getAllThingsFromDatabase({ index })
        .then(({ arrayOfThings }) => this.setState({
          index,
          arrayOfThings
        }))
    }
  )
}
```

Note that the docs also mention unsubscribing the event listener using the `.remove()` function. I put that in `ComponentWillUnmount()`.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.willFocusSubscription.remove()
}
```

There are four different events to subscribe to. I went with `willFocus` thinking it'll update before the screen is seen.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the `state` of the page and emit an action in `componentDidMount` since it is invoked immediately after a component is mounted.

References:

1. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html
2. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

**ADDED**

Since your component has been already mounted you should listen `ComonentWillReceiveProps` instead.

Comment: The previous component is already mounted, so when you pop it doesn't call componentDidMount again.

Comment: That makes sense, should you be able to hook you on ComponentWillReceiveProps?
https://gist.github.com/agrcrobles/ba6832a3ecf8c8c47c0c4101aa0a2ffe

Comment: I figured out a work-around to make it function the way I want, just wish there was an OnFocus that we could call like the other lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use react native navigation `resetTo` function. It will replace the top item and pop to it.

If we do like this `componentWillReceiveProps` will call. So we can provide the API calls in that function and make it simple.

for more details https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html#resetto