# How to refresh the first screen after poping the second screen from stack react-native-navigation V2?

Tags: android, react-native, redux, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using Wix's react-native-navigation V2 in my app for Android. When I am pushing one screen and after a pop or pressing back button the previous or first component not rendering and not executing any lifecycle method. Even we cannot use pass props in pop. I want to refresh that previous page how can I do that. I am just poping the screen as below

```
goBack = () => {

        Navigation.pop(this.props.componentId);
}
```

I found [this](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2594) issue on GitHub and it is saying that this problem could be solved by either syncing the data using Redux/MobX or listen to `visibility events` but I didn't found visibility events in V2. And don't know how to do with redux.

Comment: try this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937789/refresh-component-on-navigator-pop)

Comment: Thanks for reply but I want for Wix's react-native-navigation V2

Answer (score -1):

```
    You can follow the below steps to do so:

    1). Subscribe for react-navigation's 'didFocus' event in the component's constructor(or componentDidMount or componentWillMount).
    // Subscribe for Event
    constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.didFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
                'didFocus',
                payload => {
                    // Refresh your screen here
                }
              );
        }

2). Do not forget to unsubscribe the event when the component will unmount.
    // UnSubscribe for Event
    componentWillUnmount = () => {
            this.didFocusSubscription.remove()
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am using Wix's react-native-navigation